# How to specify an index on Bag in Nhibernate?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, indexing

I have NHibernate set up with Postgre database. I'm using mapping by code in combination with ConventionModelMapper.

NHibernate by default does not create indexes for foreign keys. For a simple column I can set foreign key using `Index` method in my `Property` mapping. However there is no such methodfor `Bag` mapping.

Will I have to define Inverse relationships to define indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define on which column of the bag mapping you want the index. It is most probably the KeyColumn

```
Bag(x => x.Collection, m => 
{
    m.Key(key => key.Column(c =>
    {
        c.Index("fooindex");
        c.Name("parent_id");
    }))
});
```